# Apache Superset installation problems

Tags: centos7, gunicorn, business-intelligence, apache-superset

We are trying to install Apache Superset. So far, we have been able to run it in standalone mode without any config file but we haven't been able to find any complete documentation, providing information on the pre-installation and configuration phases, such as:

> you have to create a linux user 'superset' and install gunicorn & superset virtual environment in it.

The configuration we are trying to achieve is a production environment to be used in company LAN,running Apache-Superset as a service, that has a self-signed certificate on Centos 7 that can be viewed via Chrome browser by granted users.

Cloud providers are not considered as an option for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you do want to create a non-root user. "superset" or some other name is fine. I'm running V1.3 (upgraded from V1.2) on CentOS 8 as user root because I'm only running in development mode right now. I have another test server using docker-compose and a non-root user. In any case, Superset runs fine either way.

As for the installation process, you should start at this URL:
https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch
There's a section for RHEL/Fedora and CentOS platforms. Follow that page all the way down to the superset run command.

As for running superset as a service, you'll need to create and enable a service file. Here's how I have my 1st test server setup/configured:

1. Created a service file name venv_superset in /etc/systemd/system. The name of the file can be whatever you want,  just as long as systemctl can find it.
2. Contents of the service file I use:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Python Venv Apache Superset service
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   User=root
   Group=root
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/ksh /usr/local/start_superset.sh
   Restart=always

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

The important setting is the `After=network.target` setting. The `ExecStart` setting is variable according to your preferred shell and script info.

As for the script I use, it's just 3 lines:

```
. /usr/local/venv/bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=superset
superset run -h 192.168.199.128 -p 8089 --with-threads --reload --debugger
```

Of course, the location of `activate`, and the host name/IP number and port number are up to you.

As for gunicorn, I never installed it explicitly, however it is installed. I don't use a self-signed cert in my test environment.

Comment: Hi , sorry for the late reply, thank you very much the detailed documentation , I had no time left to go on with bare metal installation, so had to go with docker solution, will re-install using this. Currently email problem is left, the company is using a relay mail server without username and although there is no error in superset, it doesnt send email , we are trying to resolve this, would be great to learn your thoughts on that , regards

Comment: Kayhan, actually I would stay with the docker solution going forward as it is easier to work with. As for your mail server issue, I would check the log files for error messages. I haven't configured an email server since about 10 years ago and I'm not using one now. IIRC, we used postfix on a RHEL server. There's lots of docs out on the web for troubleshooting and setup.

Comment: Is there a way to run superset using apache's httpd server via a mod_wsgi technique?

Comment: Kevin, with the docker solution,  we have been able to resolve user-nameless relay server connection problem, config file under /docker/pythondev explicitly requires parameters to override config at superset folder. Will be glad to share when needed. Regards